# Calculo de Media usando Funcao em C++

Tags: c++

Pessoal estou fazendo um programa onde ele calcula media aritimetica, harmonica e podenrada usando uma função chamada nota em C++. Na hora que vou compilar o resultado das medias só retorna 1.

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<cstdlib>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    float nota( float n1, float n2, float n3, char a, char p, char h){
    float m;
    
    cout<<"Escolha uma media: ";
    cin>>m;
    
    if(m == a){
        a = n1+n2+n3/3;
    }
    if (m==p){
        p=n1*5+n2*3+n3*2/3;
    }
    
    if (m==h){
        h=1/n1+1/n2+1/n3 /3;
    }
    
    return m;
    
    }
    char escolha;
    
    
    int main(){
    cout<<"\t        ++++++ MEDIA ++++++\n";
    cout<<"\t ======================================== \n";
    cout<<"\t |1=Aritemtica  2=Ponderada  3=Harmonica| \n";
    cout<<"\t ======================================== \n";
    
    float n1,n2,n3;
    
    cout<<"Nota do aluno:";
    cout<<"\n\n";
    
    nota;
    cout<<"Nota 1: ";
    cin>>n1;
    
    nota;
    cout<<"Nota 2: ";
    cin>>n2;
    
    nota;
    cout<<"Nota 3: ";
    cin>>n3;
    
    nota;
    cout<<"Ecolha uma media: ";
    cin>>escolha;
    
    cout<<"Media: "<<nota;
    cout<<"\n\n";
    system("pause");
    
    }
```

Comment: O código chega a compilar ? Na chamada das funções você passa os argumentos ?

Comment: Sim, compila e retorna zero nao calcula os valores das variaveis

Comment: Note que em seus `if` você está comparando `float` com `char`. Estude a precedência dos operadores, por ex. a média aritmética é calculada somando-se os 3 valores e dividindo o resultado por 3: `a = (n1+n2+n3)/3;` e não somando-se os 2 valores com 1/3 do terceiro (`a = n1+n2+n3/3;` como você fez. Idem demais médias. Este comando `nota;` não tem sentido, talvez você pretendesse chamar uma função?

Answer (score 1):

Rapaz, aqui está um código mais correto, mais próximo do que você quer fazer. Mas tem várias coisas (como já comentaram) que você precisa entender melhor, a julgar pelo código que você postou.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
    
using namespace std;
    
float nota( float n1, float n2, float n3, int escolha){
    float m;
    
    if(escolha == 1){
        m = n1+n2+n3/3;
    }
    if (escolha == 2){
        m = n1*5+n2*3+n3*2/3;
    }
    
    if (escolha == 3){
        m = 1/n1+1/n2+1/n3 /3;
    }
    
    return m;
    
}

    
    
int main(){
    cout<<"\t        ++++++ MEDIA ++++++\n";
    cout<<"\t ======================================== \n";
    cout<<"\t |1=Aritemtica  2=Ponderada  3=Harmonica| \n";
    cout<<"\t ======================================== \n";
    
    float n1,n2,n3;
    int escolha;
    
    
    cout<<"Nota do aluno:";
    cout<<"\n\n";
    
    cout<<"Nota 1: ";
    cin>>n1;
    
    cout<<"Nota 2: ";
    cin>>n2;
    
    cout<<"Nota 3: ";
    cin>>n3;
    
    cout<<"Ecolha uma media: ";
    cin>>escolha;
    
    cout<<"Media: "<<nota(n1, n2, n3, escolha);
    cout<<"\n\n";
    system("pause");
    
}
```

Comment: Valeu Obrigado, to olhando aqui o seu código e to vendo os meus erros, estou iniciando na programação como puderam perceber kkkkkkk. vou tentar fazer outros exemplos como esse para poder treinar.

Answer (score 0):

Corrigindo os cálculos das médias e removendo a duplicidade da escolha.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

float calc_media(float n1, float n2, float n3, int tipo) {
    float m;
    
    if(tipo == 1){ /* Aritmética */
        m = (n1+n2+n3)/3;
    }
    if (tipo == 2){ /* Ponderada */
        m = (n1*5+n2*3+n3*2)/(5+3+2);
    }
    
    if (tipo == 3){ /* Harmônica */
        m = 3 / (1/n1 + 1/n2 + 1/n3);
    }
    
    return m;
}
    
int main(){
    cout<<"\t       ++++++ MEDIA ++++++\n";
    cout<<"\t ======================================== \n";
    cout<<"\t |1=Aritemtica  2=Ponderada  3=Harmonica| \n";
    cout<<"\t ======================================== \n";
    
    float n1,n2,n3, media;
    int escolha;

    cout<<"Nota do aluno:";
    cout<<"\n\n";
    cout<<"Nota 1: ";
    cin>>n1;
    cout<<"Nota 2: ";
    cin>>n2;
    cout<<"Nota 3: ";
    cin>>n3;
    
    cout<<"Ecolha uma media: ";
    cin>>escolha;
    media = calc_media(n1, n2, n3, escolha);
    cout << "Media: " << media << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```